# Variadic function template accepting any pointers (to variable, function, member function, etc) as arguments

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
    void a() {};
};
int b;

template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {}

template<typename... Args>
void goo(Args*... args) {}

int main()
{
    foo(&b, &A::a); //compiles
    goo(&b, &A::a); //does not compile
}
```

Why does `goo(&a, &A::a)` not compile? Isn't `&A::a` also a pointer?

Is it possible to create a variadic function template which may accept pointers to both variables and the member functions? `foo(Args... args)` seems unsafe as I want to accept pointers only and `foo(Args... args)` could take any arguments.

Comment: How would you use `args` if you accept both pointer-to-object/function types and pointer-to-member types? `*x` doesn't work with `x = &A::a`

Comment: @Artyer I would store them and later call function template specialized for different types on each of the arguments. So the syntax would be the same for all arguments, but the behaviour would differ depending on the type of the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, pointers-to-members are not really pointers, in the sense that they don't store a (single) address. `std::is_pointer` returns `false` for them.

Pointers to functions, on the other hand, *are* pointers.

---

If you want to write a function that accepts only pointers-to-members (including member functions), do this:

```
template <typename ...A, typename ...B>
void goo(A B::*... args) {}
```

If you want a single function to accept both regular pointers and pointers-to-membrs, you'll either have to use `requires` (needs C++20):

```
template <typename ...Args>
requires((std::is_pointer_v<Args> || std::is_member_pointer_v<Args>) && ...)
void foo(Args ...args) {}
```

...or SFINAE:

```
template <typename ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<((std::is_pointer_v<Args> || std::is_member_pointer_v<Args>) && ...)>>
void foo(Args ...args) {}
```